# How did renv know if a package is used? Happens in new package(in new project seems fine.)

Tags: r, renv

I am using renv package 1.0.3 to manage my project library.

Using `renv::status()` method, we get something like:

```
 package      installed recorded used  
 nnet         y         y        n
```

So that means I have nnet package installed by `renv::install` and recorded in renv.lock file. However, my hello.R file under the folder R in project test_project(path test_project/R/hello.R) contains these lines:

```
renv::install("nnet")
library(nnet)
which.is.max(c(1,2)) #the method defined in nnet
```

However, I kept on running `renv::status()` and `renv::snapshot()`

the line for nnet and col for used still shows 'n'

you can see the pic snap here:

[image]

The hello.R file snap is here:

[image]

How was the renv aware of which package is used and if it couldn't get the correct info how could we notify renv?

Comment: Did you set `update = TRUE` to allow `snapshot` updating the lockfile? To see, how {renv} tracks the dependencies, see `?dependencies`.

Comment: @I_O in dependencies I could see it but in status not, I don't know why. Adding update just tells renv.lock to do appending instead of replacing, it doesn't tell r the package is used some where, I will upload a pic as evidence

Answer (score 1):

I think I find the answer myself, So I post it here.

Using renv, the behaviors in new package and new project are different.

you can use `renv::settings$snapshot.type()` to check it status.

If in 'implicit' mode, as by default in new project, once you save your change like `library(tictoc)`, the renv will treat it as used.(but not its dependencies, those will get recorded as used once installed).

If in 'explicit' mode, as by default in new package, you can only record the package as used once it was added in the DESCRIPTION files using Imports or Depends.